# Show that if vertex cover is reducible to a mod-inverse than P=NP

Tags: p-vs-np, polynomial-time-reductions, vertex-cover

> Let **MOD-INVERSE** consist of all pairs $\langle N,c \rangle$ such that $c$ has an inverse modulo $N$.
>
> Let **VERTEX-COVER** consist of all pairs $\langle G,k \rangle$ such that $G$ is an undirected graph with a vertex cover of size $k$.
>
> Prove that if **VERTEX-COVER** reduces to **MOD-INVERSE** then P=NP**.

**My Thoughts :**

$\langle N,c \rangle$ is a member of MOD-INVERSE iff $\gcd(N,c) = 1$.
So we have to show that if VERTEX-COVER is reducible to MOD-INVERSE then P=NP.
Now P is the class of all problems that can be solved in polynomial time and NP are those
that have polynomial time verifiers.
I found out that VERTEX-COVER is NP-Complete. That means that it's NP-HARD.
Does NP-HARD mean that given any problem in NP, VERTEX-COVER can be reduced to that problem?

I am somewhat confused here: do I have to use this heavy fact, that VERTEX-COVER is NP-complete, in order to solve the question?
If VERTEX-COVER  is reducible to MOD-INVERSE then VERTEX-COVER would be in P and since it is
NP-HARD, all problems in NP would be in P.

Not sure if that's a correct argument.

Comment: Please don't use manual line breaks. They don't show well on other devices.

Comment: You have a complete argument. In what sense are you not sure that it is correct? Is there some specific step you are not sure about?